# VB how to access the properties of the class by the name?

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I do have a class ClientClass with multiple properties. Each object loads client's data from the database. There are also two arrays PropertyName and DBField, which I use as dictionary to get each property (assume all values are strings for simplicity).

client is an object of ClientClass and clientrecord is a recordset - a record in DB table

in short I would like to go through my properties and assign them values from DB like

```
Public Class ClientClass
    Public person_name As String
    Public person_lastname As String
    Public person_middlename As String

    Public person_firmFlag As String
    Public person_firmName As String
End Class

// then in the code:
for i=1 to n 'n is a number of properties
```

> ```
> client.{property(propertyname(i)).value}=clientrecord.Fields(DBFields(i)).value.tostring
> ```

```
next i
```

what is the proper way to address properties of client object in this case?

thanks!

Comment: Those are instance Fields, not properties. You should describe what kind of tools you use to retrieve data from your database and what objects you get as result. If you need simple object mapping features, take a look at [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)

Comment: This isn't trivial to set up and do.  If your number of properties is manageable, you're better off doing it by hand.  If you really need it to be automated like this, you'll need to set up something based on associating a [reference to the setter] to the [property index].  That will involve reflection (which is slow) so make sure to do it once up-front.  An ORM (as mentioned in the previous comment) will have the machinery to do this for you and you would then only need to provide the configuration.